# Migrating from SVN to Bitbucket- Having issues with my scenarios [Tried multiple methods from past 2 weeks-yet Failed]

Tags: git, svn, version-control, bitbucket

Please Read out with patience(as I really want to convey my problem) **Maybe at the end everything will make sense :)**

So From last two weeks I am continuously trying every single methods/solutions to migrate already existing projects in SVN to Bitbucket!

**Context** : I am a fresher and totally new to these systems, though my organization expects from me to migrate existing SVN repositories to Bitbucket.

**Requirement** : To move trunk , partial branches and latest two tags!

**How actually I started**:

1) First with trunk folders to Bitbucket :

For that I created a repository  in bitbucket through UI -> then cloned it in local-> then placed trunk files in local directory-> did git add,commit and push.

Got my trunk files in master branch.

2) Then I started with Branches, (as I needed only few of the branches!) :

For that I created one branch in bitbucket repository.
then I created one folder in local->git init->used git remote add remotebranch  -> git fetch remotebranch -> git checkout  -> copied content of branch from svn to this local folder -> Then again add, commit and push!

Up to this step I got my trunk and branch created successfully as per my understanding. (Don't know I was doing it the right way or not)

3) Then I started onto tags! (which was a pain), I wasn't able to migrate specific tags but somehow I found a way to migrate all tags to my repository in Bitbucket.

using one blog : http://www.sailmaker.co.uk/blog/2013/05/05/migrating-from-svn-to-git-preserving-branches-and-tags-3/#push-for-real

I used only git push --tags origin option from there!

---

Seems like organization is not happy with my approach and they want everything in proper way, with there conditions,i.e. all history, trunks , selective branches and selective tags to be migrated.

---

Maybe my approach was not at at all valid from your side too! but I really have no Idea about how these things works and how to meet there requirements.

I have tried many solutions but nothing works out for me at one shot!
I even think SVN provided to me don't uses stdlayout! i.e, 1 repository have folders( branches, tags and trunk) , branches contain (many branches--I don't have any idea what and how they works, I just have to migrate it selectively-> say 2 out of 15!) ,tags again contain multiple tags(but I need only specific tags!) , trunk sometimes have 2 or more sub-folders and inside them they contains different project files ( I was asked to treat 2 subfolders as separate repositories in bitbucket and follow 1 master contain one project rule)

Trust me I have followed every solution with all my understanding! Got no answer for my situation!

It would be helpful if someone will be able to give some solution here instead of further references.

Thanks for baring with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to migrate SVN with branches and tags, you should **keep the history of SVN repo during migration**.

Steps to migrate svn repo to git repo with trunk and part of branches and tags as below:

###Step1: use git svn command
Use the command to fetch all the revisions by:

```
git svn clone <SVN repo URL> --branches=branches --tags=tags --trunk=trunk
```

All the branches and tags of the svn repo will be stored in `.git/refs/remotes/origin` and `.git/refs/remotes/origin/tags`. You can check the branches and tags by `git branch -r`. And the output looks like:

```
origin/branch1
origin/branch2
...
origin/branchN
origin/tags/tag1
origin/tags/tag2
...
origin/tags/tagX
origin/tags/tagM
```

###Step2: get part of the branches and tags you want to migrate
You just need to checkout the branches and create tags you want to migrate to git repo.
Such as above example:

- If you want to migrate `branch1` and `branchN` to git repo, then you can checkout the two branches by:

  ```
    git checkout -b branch1 origin/branch1 
    git checkout -b branchN origin/branchN
  ```
- If you want to migrate `tagX` and `tagM` into git repo, then you can create by below commands:

  ```
    git tag -a tagX origin/tags/tagX -m 'migrate tagX into git repo'
    git tag -a tagM origin/tags/tagM -m 'migrate tagM into git repo'
  ```

###Step3: add remote and push to remote git repo
Then you can add remote (bitbucket repo) in the local git repo and push the local branches and tags into bitbucket repo:

```
git remote add bitbucket <birbucket repo URL>
git push bitbucket -f --all             #push all the local branches (master, branch1 and branchN) 
git push bitbucket --tags               #push tags you created (tagX and tagM)
```

Now in the bitbucket repo, it only contains the history for trunk and part branches (`master`, `branch1` and `branchN`) and tags (`tagX` and `tagM`).

Comment: Thanks Marina! I am trying the solution provided by you, meanwhile is there any method to choose tags and branches while cloning, so that we would clone only the required part of the SVN repository in first step?

Comment: Yes, you can clone with part of branches and tags during git svn clone. Such as `git svn clone <SVN repo URL> --branches=branches/branch1 --branches=branches/branchN --tags=tags/tagX --tags=tags/tagM --trunk=trunk`.

Comment: @NikhilKumar And if the answer helps you solve the problem, can you mark the answer by clicking √ symbol on the left of the answer? And it will also benefit others who meet similar questions.

Comment: This answer helped me solve my problem. Being new to stackoverflow my upvotes are recorded but aren't visible.